# Pyside6 concurent image reading blocks main thread

Tags: python, concurrency, pyqt, pyside

Despite concurrent loading of images, ui hangs when loading folder with many images.

Method description:
On callback pixmap loader creates futures, that are added immediately to model. Model `data` method returns `None` if future is still working and pixmap if it is ready. QListView displays pixmaps with a help of the delegate.

However, all futures already have finished they job, when `data` is called and before that main ui hangs for a moment. User never sees placeholder pixmap.

Interesting things happens when I add `QThread.msleep` in the concurent future-worker. Then, user start seeing placeholder image (`data()` returned `None`). However time to achieve loading of all images is long - many threads sleep for more than 100ms.

```
# callback
def on_load_directory(image_filenames):
   images_futures = [pixmap_loader.load(image_name) for image_name in image_filenames]
   logger.debug("Futures ready, adding to model")
   self.pixmap_model.add_pixmaps(images_futures)

# model
def data(self, index, role):
     annotated_pixmap_future = self.pixmaps[index.row()]
     if not annotated_pixmap_future.is_finished():
         logger.debug("i never return none")
         return None

     annotated_pixmap = annotated_pixmap_future.get()
     if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        return annotated_pixmap


# delegate
def paint(self, painter, option, index):        
    pixmap = index.data(Qt.DecorationRole)
    if not pixmap_thumbnail:
        pixmap = self.placeholder
    # ...


# loading image:
def _read(self, filename: str|Path) -> AnnotatedPixmap:
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(str(filename)))
    thumbnail = pixmap.scaled(self.thumbnail_size, self.thumbnail_size,    aspectMode=Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    return AnnotatedPixmap(pixmap, thumbnail, str(filename))

def load(self, filename: str|Path) -> SimpleFutureWorker[AnnotatedPixmap]:
    worker = SimpleFutureWorker(self._read, filename=filename)
    worker.signals.result.connect(self._on_load_finished)
    self.load_cache[(str(filename))] = True
    self.thread_pool.start(worker)
    return worker

# future
# simple - maybe need some refactoring, but it works
class SimpleFutureWorker(Generic[T], QRunnable):

    _SEMAPHORE_GUADS = 1000

    def __init__(self, fn: Callable[..., T], *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleFutureWorker, self).__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        self.result = None
        self._is_running = False
        self._is_finished = False
        # maybe could be done better with latch but I don't know if qt has one
        self._semaphore = QSemaphore(SimpleFutureWorker._SEMAPHORE_GUADS)
        self._semaphore.acquire(SimpleFutureWorker._SEMAPHORE_GUADS)

        # Add the callback to our kwargs
        # self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

    def run(self) -> None:
        '''
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        '''
        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        self._is_running = True
        try:
            # Sleeping thread - optional.
            # from PySide6.QtCore import QThread
            # QThread.msleep(100)
            self.result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(self.result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self._is_finished = True
            self._is_running = True
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done
            self._semaphore.release(SimpleFutureWorker._SEMAPHORE_GUADS)

    def is_finished(self) -> bool:
        return self._is_finished
    
    def is_running(self) -> bool:
        return self._is_running
    
    def get(self) -> T:
        self._semaphore.acquire(1)
        result = self.result
        self._semaphore.release(1)
        return result
```

Dealing with concurency with Python with GIL and control that is given and taken back by Qt seems to be very tricky. I wonder what exactly is happening here and if there is any good solution.

Comment: Your approach seems quite convoluted. Also, creating a QRunnable for *every* image doesn't seem very effective, and you could instead consider a *single* long-running thread that would be "fed" with the data using a queue or a signal (if you're using a standard QThread running its own event loop), and emit its own signal whenever an image has been loaded. Also note that QPixmap is not thread safe and shouldn't be created outside the main thread; use QImage instead.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for your suggestion on QImage. My solution indeed is quite complicated, but see that QRunnable is managed by ThreadPool, so not every runnable==thread

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details such as a log including timing information in the ```_read()```. The GIL is not the cause of the problem because it is released when calling Qt native(C++) methods.